# Openshift custom resources restrictions

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rbac

I didn't get how I can restrict the access of custom resources in Openshift using RBAC

let's assume I have a custom api:

```
apiVersion: yyy.xxx.com/v1
kind: MyClass
metadata:
   ...
```

Is it possible to prevent some users to deploy resources where `apiVersion=yyy.xxx.com/v1` and `kind=MyClass`?

Also can I grant access to other users to deploy resources where `apiVersion=yyy.xxx.com/v1` and `kind=MyOtherClass`?

If this can be done using RBAC roles, how can I deploy RBAC roles in Openshift? only using CLI or I can create some yaml configuration files and deploy them with Yaml for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cluster roles and RBAC roles:

```
oc adm policy add/remove-cluster-role-to-group oauth:system:authenticated
```

So the general idea is to remove the permission to deploy the resource to all the authenticated users.
The next step is to add the permission to deploy that resourse only to ServicesAccounts assigned to specific namepsaces

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift/Kubernetes has Cluster Role/Binding and Local Role/Binding.

Here is the definitions in the docs. *1

```
Cluster role/binding: Roles and bindings that are applicable across all projects. Cluster roles exist cluster-wide, and cluster role bindings can reference only cluster roles.

Local role/binding: Roles and bindings that are scoped to a given project. While local roles exist only in a single project, local role bindings can reference both cluster and local roles.
```

If your Custom Resource is the resource existing in a single namespace. You can manage to give permission to others.

Whereas, if the Custom Resource is the cluster wide resource, cluster admin can only deploy the resource.

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/authentication/using-rbac.html